# Rails Friend friender/contact importer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

Are there any gems available or a good way to go about making a friend finder to find friends that are using my service? Also, I am using omniauth with devise if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well quite easy...

as long as the user is connected to your facebook app (e.g.) you can query the service for his friendslist and search in your database for all user who have "this" user id.

you also can lookup their names but it might be more effective if you challenge their ids.

Comment: thank you. I agree. That would work. At the time I was looking for a quick solution. A gem already made to use with devise.